# Filter unbound combo on opening

Tags: ms-access

I have been using multiple forms that are exactly the same except they have different filtering e.g. frmChecklists-Group1; frmChecklists-Group2.
I realised I can just have frmChecklists, and use control buttons on a "switchboard form", such as 'Group 1', 'Group 2' etc. which open the form and apply the relevant query.
HOWEVER, I have on each form an unbound combo box that lists the members of the group, and has an 'after update go to matching record' macro.
What I need to happen: I click "Group 1" command button; frmChecklists opens with qryGroup1 applied; and my combo box is also filtered by qryGroup1. But I can't work out how to attach the query to the combo box on opening.

Comment: VBA code sets combobox RowSource property. What does "can't work out" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What is your code? Edit question.

Comment: Or combobox RowSource has SQL with criteria that references a control (another combobox or a textbox) on form that has the group identifier. If a different group is selected, Requery the members combobox. This is called 'conditional' or 'cascading' or 'dependent' combobox/listbox and is a common topic.